# Making Connected User with stripe android + firebase

Tags: java, android, node.js, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm very new to working with backend server stuff and nodejs. I'm trying to set up Stripe with my app and now trying to create a Connected account with stripe. Was following this https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide but I don't understand enough to make it work. How do I get information from the server or send it through to make the account.

this is what I got so far

```
        binding.connectWithStripe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String redirect = "https://www.example.com/connect-onboard-redirect";

                String url = "https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize" +
                        "?client_id=" + "ca_Hdth53g5sheh4w4hwhw5h4weh5" +
                        "&state=" + 1234 +
                        "&redirect_uri=" + redirect;
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(view.getContext(), Uri.parse(url));
            }
        });
```

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const { resolve } = require("path");

const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_xxxx');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // Display landing page.
  const path = resolve("./index.html");
  res.sendFile(path);
});

app.get("/connect/oauth", async (req, res) => {
  const { code, state } = req.query;

  // Assert the state matches the state you provided in the OAuth link (optional).
  if(!stateMatches(state)) {
    return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Incorrect state parameter: ' + state });
  }

  // Send the authorization code to Stripe's API.
  stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code
  }).then(
    (response) => {
      var connected_account_id = response.stripe_user_id;
      saveAccountId(connected_account_id);

      // Render some HTML or redirect to a different page.
      return res.status(200).json({success: true});
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err.type === 'StripeInvalidGrantError') {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Invalid authorization code: ' + code});
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({error: 'An unknown error occurred.'});
      }
    }
  );
});

const stateMatches = (state_parameter) => {
  // Load the same state value that you randomly generated for your OAuth link.
  const saved_state = 'sv_53124';

  return saved_state == state_parameter;
}

const saveAccountId = (id) => {
  // Save the connected account ID from the response to your database.
  console.log('Connected account ID: ' + id);
}

app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${4242}!`));
```

The sign up page opens and can enter the test info but after submiting it's not actually creating the account in Stripe dashboard. Any help would be much appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTJAH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you complete the Express account sign up, Stripe redirects your customer to the redirect URI you specified on your Connect OAuth url (looks like yours is https://www.example.com/connect-onboard-redirect).

You should redirect to a real page of yours here. The redirect URL will append query params containing the authorization code e.g. `https://www.example.com/connect-onboard-redirect?code=ac_1234`

where `ac_1234` is the OAuth authorization code.

You need to parse out that authorization code and send it to your backend and complete the OAuth connection to actually connect that Express account to your Platform: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts#token-request

Comment: I got the first part. Now how would i process that oAuth with the node.js code I have there?

Comment: Ok i foudn out i needed to use Retrofit(or anything along the lines that can make calls from backend) Now it's just not authorizing. I just need to read up on all that and figure out how it all works. Thanks for answer. Just some learning on my end i need to do

Comment: used *Volley sry

Answer (score 0):

Got the last piece of my puzzle. Didn't know how to communicate with nodejs and use the GET method. I used volley with this piece of code

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://10.0.2.2:4242" + "/connect/oauth",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.d(">>>>>>>>CONNECTED?", ">>>CONNECTED!!!<<<");
                                // enjoy your response
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>ERRRRRRROR", error.toString());
                        // enjoy your error status
                    }
                });

                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Hope that helps anyone else starting to learn nodejs :)